# Coredata: import/export objects from xml

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to write some functions that import/export only some objects of certain entity from the database of CoreData. I have googled and I found not much helpful hints so far... the only one example that helped me is this tutorial: [MultiThreding code sample from this site](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data)

somehow I could magage to export objects in XML, but in this example, "import" doesn't work... I looked into the source code of PPImportOperation.m and it seems that the function **copyRecipe:(NSManagedObject*)recipe** has some issues... then I read well the whole source code and I felt that there would be more simple and easier solution for getting objects' data from XML, maybe by using NSXmlParser or NSXMLNode (NSXMLNodePreserveCDATA,NSXMLNodeisCDATA)... or if you can tell me some other simple solution to get import function work, your help is appreciated. I'm not an experienced coder (I began Objective-C recently) so please answer me in details with example code, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [blog.sallarp.com](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/) for some example code that imports objects from XML using NSXMLParser.